# Displaying BufferedImage directly in JavaFX

Tags: image-processing, javafx, image-manipulation, bufferedimage

I'm making a **raster image editor in JavaFX**, and all the imaging libraries I've found use `BufferedImage`. Problem is, I can't display a `BufferedImage` in a JavaFX app, without converting it to `javafx.scene.image.Image` first. I'm concerened about speed here; **if I'm constantly converting between `BufferedImage` and JavaFX's `Image`, the UI will lag**.

For example, if the user wants to draw a line with the pencil tool, I'm constantly updating the image in the UI. Every time they move the cursor, I have to convert between `BufferedImage` and JavaFX's `Image`, which I'm sure will make the line appear laggy as it's being drawn.

The libraries I've found are [ImgLib2](http://fiji.sc/ImgLib2), [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html), [Apache Commons Imaging Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html), and [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/). All of them use `BufferedImage`. I haven't found an imaging library yet that uses JavaFX
's `Image`.

So my question is: **how do I display a `BufferedImage` directly in JavaFX?** I'm reluctant to go back to AWT. Alternatively, is there an imaging library that uses JavaFX's `Image` instead of `BufferedImage`?

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) to display a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) in JavaFX without first converting the image to a JavaFX [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html).

I do not know if this would be any more performant than doing an image conversion, you would have to do some benchmarking with your application to see.

In general, I'd probably recommend doing a conversion over putting a BufferedImage in a SwingNode.  With a SwingNode you will need to be careful how you manage threading and I think benchmarking using a SwingNode will not yield you the performance increase you are looking for.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a conversion is recommended over a SwingNode?